# Unknown error using Swift 3 in xcode 8 - "Editor placeholder in source file"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am creating a helper function to handle what happens when a register button is clicked. I am attempting to connect Firebase database and use the reference that I create to input the information that is inputed. I am getting the following two errors upon finishing the function...

```
"Editor placeholder in source file"
"Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped, did you mean '!' or '?'?"
```

The first error is the one I am most concerned about, but all pointers would be appreciated.

Here is the function that I have created to handle the RegisterButtonClick action:

```
func handleRegisterClick(){
        guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let name = nameTextField.text else{
            print("Form is not valid...")
            return
        }

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error ?? "user was not created... something went wrong")
                return
            }
            // else... succesfully authernticated user

            var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
            ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

            let values = ["name": name, "email": email]

            ref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                if err != nil{
                    print(err ?? "Child values could not be updated... something went wrong")
                    return
                }
                print("Saved user successfully into the Firebase DB")
            })
        })
        print("Register Button was pressed.")
    }
```

Up above is where the error is being called. The following block of code shows where this function is being called:

```
lazy var loginRegisterButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 80, g: 101, b: 161)
        button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegisterClick), for: .touchUpInside)

        // this next step is needed or else the constraints set later on will not work
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
```

Any help fixing the first error would be extremely helpful. I just don't understand what the error is stating. Very new to iOS development, therefore apologies on any unclarity.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode inserts placeholders in your code when using autocomplete. You should replace them with your own values. That first error means you left one of those placeholders in your code. It should look visually different, with a rounded "pill-like" background of a different color. Find it and replace it or remove it.

The second error means you have an optional String (`String?`) that you have to unwrap using `!` or `?` to turn it into a non-optional `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
(user: FIRUser?, error)
```

should be

```
(user, error)
```

That should correct both errors. If not, please indicate the line the optional error is occurring on and I will update the answer.